# Find the coordinates on surface of hemicube of polygons within same solid angle.

Tags: geometry

[image: Diagram for the Problem Statement]

I'm stuck at the start of the problem.
When the user asked to Enter inputs of $P_1(x,y)$ and $P_2(x,y)$ coordinates.
I need to compute the coordinates of $P_1'(x,y)$ and $P_2'(x,y)$ from the figure shown.

To my knowledge I can say that if we consider the coordinates of $P_1' (x,y)$ as $(xxx,1)$ and $P_2'$ $(xxx,1)$ I'm stuck in finding the $x$-coordinates of $P_1'$ and $P_2'$.

Any suggestions on this problem it would be helpful.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your diagram isn't entirely clear: Is this a two-dimensional problem? If so, then you can use the similarity of the small and large triangles to equate their proportions.

Comment: Yes it is two dimensional.the rectangle on the plane is hemicube.I just want to find out the Coordinates of P'1 and P'2.

Comment: Ok. Then $P_1$ and $P_1'$ both lie on the same line through the origin. What does that tell you about the proportions of their components?

Comment: Sorry I'm really weak at Geometry and Calculations.Could you explain me clearly.If I give the Coordinates like P1(3,4) P2(5,4) then what would be the algorithm to find the coordinates of P1' and P2'.